# What does the word ''tiny man'' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

In this following context, should I take the phrase "this tiny man" to be a 'homunculus'?

How should I understand the meaning of the bold and italic phrase in the following paragraph?

> Under the influence of the newest knowledge the psychologists already
> begin to realize the truth about the delusive nature of the ego-
> entity, the mere relative value of the ego-feeling, ***the great
> dependency of this tiny man on the inexhaustible and complex working
> factors of the whole world...***

[*Collected Wheel Publications Volume XXVI:*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Collected_Wheel_Publications_Volume_XXVI/Dgc4BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The+idea+of+an+independent+ego%22+%22this+tiny+man%22&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

I take the intent of the author as trying to diminish the value of the "ego-entity" by referring to it as "tiny". The phrase "tiny man" can be used to refer to persons thought to have low moral or intellectual "stature". One can develop an image of a little, narrow-minded man sitting within a person's cranium, somewhat unconsciously going about his daily business but not attending to higher goals.

Answer (score 0):

In this passage, it is apparent that "tiny man" is a metaphor for "ego".

Comment: What is your idea about the last phrase,  bold and italic? @James K.

Comment: That is a question to ask on [buddhism.se].  There may be a deep meaning in the philosophy, but  otherwise it just means the "great (large, important) dependency of the ego on the inexhaustible (never-ending) and complex (many parts) working factors (functional elements) of the whole world (of the universe)